# Vue 3 composition API get value from object ref

Tags: typescript, ref, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a `ref`:

```js
const editItem = ref<object | null>(null)
```

Here's an example value for it:

```js
{
   id: 1,
   title: 'Harry Potter',
   author: 'J.K. Rowling',
   created: '30-08-2000',
}
```

If I run `console.log(editItem.value)`, I see this object:

[image]

But when I try to read the value's `author` with `console.log(editItem.value.author)`, then I see this error:

> ```
> Object is possibly 'null'.
> ```

Comment: could you provide an example in codesandbox? you could enrich this one https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-ts-y7bdv

Answer (score 2):

Since the type of the ref is `object | null`, it *could* be `null` when you access it, leading to a runtime exception. The error message is warning about that possibility for `editItem.value`.

You could either add a `null`-check around its access:

```js
if (editItem.value) {
  console.log(editItem.value.author)
}
```

...or you could simply use [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining):

```js
console.log(editItem.value?.author)
```

But you'll notice that you'll get a different warning about `author` not being part of the signature for `object`. One solution is to change the `ref`'s type from `object` to a specific interface:

```js
interface MyRef {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  author: string;
  created: string;
}

const editItem = ref<MyRef | null>(null)

console.log(editItem.value?.author) ✅
```

Answer (score 1):

Cześć Michal

The issue (without seeing the code) seems to be that you are using ref for a object value. While you may find some workaround to get it to work, the simplest way to deal with reactive objects is to use `reactive` instead of `ref`.

One additional benefit is that you won't need to use `.value` when you're getting or setting the object value.

Comment: Thank you, that solved an issue I was facing. Not clear enough in the `Vue.js` documentation.