# Object is possibly 'null'. on a ref(null)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Learning Vue Composition API (and TypeScript), from the docs I found, I should be using `ref(null)` to use by a sub component I have inside `<template>...</template>`.

This subcomponent have methods like `open()`, and I'm accessing it like this:

```
setup() {
    const subcomponentRef= ref(null);
    subcomponentRef.value.open();
    return { subcomponentRef };
}
```

This I agree may show the error `Object is possibly 'null'.` pointed to `subcomponentRef.value`, but the weird thing is even if I added a condition `if (subcomponentRef !== null && subcomponentRef.value !== null) { ... }`, it still shows that error. **Why??**

Also tried accessing it like `subcomponentRef?.value?.open()` but I receive this error `Property 'open' does not exist on type 'never'.`.

Also tried adding a *Non-null assertions*, like `confirmation.value!.open();` and receives same error `Property 'open' does not exist on type 'never'.`.

Any idea what's wrong here? or maybe instead of using `ref(null)`, I should predefine it with the actual component? but I don't have idea how to do that correctly, can't find in docs.

Comment: it looks like you're referencing a component, please share how did you import it

Comment: I'm exactly using NuxtJS and its component module that auto registers the components, but lets say I don't use it, I would do it like `import subcomponent from './subcomponent.vue';` and on template `<subcomponent ref="subcomponentRef" />`

Answer (score 14):

Great question! I had the same issue as you and stumbled upon this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64613226/vue-3-composition-api-get-value-from-object-ref). What worked for me was defining the shape of the object (a typescript interface), so TS knows what is there and what isn't.

Applying this knowledge to your example:

```js
setup() {
    const subcomponentRef = ref(null)
    subcomponentRef.value.open() // TS error here
}
```

Becomes:

```js
setup() {
    const subcomponentRef = ref<null | { open: () => null }>(null)
    subcomponentRef.value?.open()
}
```

The TS error is now gone because:

- Typescript knows the function `open` is available on `subcomponentRef` because we [declared](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#our-first-interface) it upfront
- With [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) we tell Typescript not to look further when `subcomponentRef.value` is `null` or `undefined`.

Usually these interfaces are already provided somewhere and don't need to be created manually. So in my case I just had to use the `QInput` interface from `quasar` to avoid the TS error of `resetValidation` not being available:

```js
import { QInput } from 'quasar'

const driverIdInput = ref<QInput>()
driverIdInput.value?.resetValidation()
```

I hope this helps to clear things up and avoid these nasty errors.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your help with this. Here's my simplified solution for focusing an input element in Vue 3 Composition API, using Typescript:

```
<template>
   <input ref="inputField">
</template>

const inputField = ref(null)
inputField.value.focus()      // ERROR:  TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'
```

Solution:

```
const inputField = ref<null | { focus: () => null }>(null)
if(inputField.value) {    
    inputField.value.focus()
}
```

Ensures a focus function is defined.

Comment: I'm afraid this solution doesn't work. Only optional chaining does remove the error

Answer (score 2):

You should use the component type using `typeof yourComponent` or `null` then use `?` optional chaining to access methods/properties:

```
setup() {
    const subcomponentRef= ref < typeof subcomponent| null > (null);
    subcomponentRef.value?.open();
    return { subcomponentRef };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that you are not typing the ref. You always need to add a type to ref if that ref does not only have the type you use initally.

You need to add a type to the ref, assuming your component is a MySubcomponent

```js
// In this case, you need to type
const subcomponentRef = ref<ComponentPublicInstance<typeof MySubcomponent> | null>(null);

// In this case not, type is inferred to Ref<number>
const myRef = ref(15)
```

Then you can use your if and access the methods of your component instance inside it. Mind that you can only access it after setup has completed, so e.g. in event listeners, the mounted hook, …

Answer (score 1):

If you are here for declaring nullable number reference in vue composition API with Typescript,

```js
setup() {
  const foo = ref<number | null>(null);

  const someAction = () => {
      foo.value = 1
  }

  return { foo, someAction };
}
```

On the above code snippet,
you can change the `number` data type to match your desired data type.
Also, you can add multiple possible data types if required by using the `|` operator.

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite straightforward, you just tell TS it's in fact not null by using [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```js
setup() {
  const foo = ref(null);

  onMounted(() => {
    foo!.someMethod();
  }

  return { foo };
}
```

Comment: This will only work, if your type is null | SomeOtherType.

In this case the type is null. So while ! tells typescript that it may not be null, TS still has no type information on the acutal type and will complain that someMethod is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try `any` as a type if nothing works !.

```
setup() {

const buttonRef= ref<any>(null); // <-- highlight

const buttonClicked = () => { buttonRef.value.clicked = true }

return { buttonClicked, buttonRef }

}
```