# How to assign class to template ref? -- VueJS 3 Typescript Component API

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How do I add/remove CSS classes from a template ref using the Vue 3 Composition API and typescript?

I am running into the following typescript errors for `modal.value`:

1. `const modal = ref(null)` returns *Object is possibly 'null'.*
2. `const modal = ref<HTMLDivElement | undefined>()` return *Object is possibly 'undefined'.*

```
<template>
    <button @click="hideModal">Hide</button>
    <div class="show" ref="modal"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
    ...
    setup(){
        const modal = ref(null)
        const hideModal = () => modal.value.classList.remove('show')

        return {modal, hideModal}
    }
})
</script>
```

---

These two options work, however, could someone explain if this is or is not a preferred method.

**Option A:**

```
const modal = ref()
const hideModal = () => modal.value.classList.remove('show')
```

**Option B:**

```
const modal = ref({})
const hideModal = () => (modal.value as HTMLDivElement).classList.remove('show')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object is possibly 'null'. on a ref(null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65026253/object-is-possibly-null-on-a-refnull)

Comment: @StevenB. Thank you, but not quite. I just added a couple of options which seem to work, but I do not know if they are "preferred" implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM manipulation should be avoided because Vue will overwrite those changes if the component needs to be rerendered.

You could use a [class binding](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes) instead. That would also obviate the template ref (`modal`) if it were only intended for modifying the element's class list:

```html
<template>
    <button @click="hideModal">Hide</button>
    <div :class="{ show: isShown }"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
    setup(){
        const isShown = ref(false)
        const hideModal = () => isShown.value = true

        return { isShown, hideModal }
    }
})
</script>
```

If your style for the `show` class is only setting CSS `visibility`, consider using the [`v-show` directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-show) instead:

```html
<div v-show="isShown"></div>
```

...or the [`v-if` directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-show):

```html
<div v-if="isShown"></div>
```